# Access Video ninja URL using python

Tags: python, video-streaming

I am trying to access a video ninja room URL (https://vdo.ninja/view.........) using python.
I have tried opencv, requests, ffmpeg,... nothing worked.
Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: Try selenium...